# JQuery part of code not working Hide / Show nearest

Tags: jquery

Hi I'm trying get the nearest button to the one I hide show after I hide it, so I'm using this code:

```
//html

<a class="button1" href="#">Button1 Click me</a>
<a class="button2" href="#" style="display:none;">Button2 Here</a>


//JQuery

$('.button1').click(function() {

  $(this).closest(".button1").hide('slow'); //This works (Hides)

  $(this).closest(".button2").show('slow'); //This does not show


});
```

The first button is hiding but the button under that is not showing.

What I'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: because you are doing wrong in first line you command `this.closest` that means he can never found that element because the element is hidden

Comment: @TheMechanic `.closest()` looks for a `parent`, not a `sibling`. It doesn't matter whether it's displayed or not.

Comment: It's working when the OP uses it to show that element because the traverse starts with the element itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.closest()` traverses the DOM looking for the target's parent element, starting with the target itself (that's why it works when you try to show that element). What you're looking for is a sibling (`.siblings()`, `.prev()` or `.next()`).

In your case, `.next()` would be the choice:

```js
$(function () {
    $('.button1').on('click', function () {
        // Toggle the clicked element display (block/none).
        $(this).toggle('slow');
        // Toggle the clicked element next sibling with class 
        // button2 display (block/none).
        $(this).next('.button2').toggle('slow');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="button1" href="#">Button1 Click me</a>
<a class="button2" href="#" style="display:none;">Button2 Here</a>
<a class="button1" href="#">Button1 Click me</a>
<a class="button2" href="#" style="display:none;">Button2 Here</a>
<a class="button1" href="#">Button1 Click me</a>
<a class="button2" href="#" style="display:none;">Button2 Here</a>
```

[Demo (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/ncts4n2k/1/)

[jQuery API .closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

[jQuery API .siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

[jQuery API .next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

[jQuery API .prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to navigate up from your clicked button. Go for something like this instead:

```js
$(".button1").hide('slow');
$(".button2").show('slow');
```

If it's toggling you want, you could do this:

```js
$('.button1, .button2').click(function() {
    $(this)
        .hide('slow');
        .siblings()
        .show('slow');
});
```

Comment: I have to use: $(this).closest(".button1").hide('slow'); as there's not only one. There's lots in rows so I have to only hide/show the specific one clicked

Comment: In that case, the toggling solution should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I get it what you are doing wrong just put this snippet in your code and it works

```
$('.button1').click(function() {
    $(this).hide('slow');
    $(this).next().show('slow');    
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tg1ex9dq/)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with such solution. Searching for .button is wrong-you will search whole DOM, and you are interested only in those two particular buttons. Either give them ids, or use code below.

```
//html
<div class="button-container">
  <a class="button1" href="#">Button1 Click me</a>
  <a class="button2" href="#" style="display:none;">Button2 Here</a>
<div>

//JQuery
$('.button1').click(function() {
  var buttonContainer = $(this).closest(".button-container");
  // you will search for those buttons only inside your container, it will be much faster than plain $('.button1')
  buttonContainer.find('.button1').hide('slow');
  buttonContainer.find('.button2').show('slow');    
});
```